# When will the "Dragon Ball Z" movie be released worldwide?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Please tell me when the "Dragon Ball Z" movie will be released worldwide? I have been waiting for a long time. I saw the trailer in 2009, but the movie is not out yet. So please help me to find out the exact date.

Comment: Why don't you [ask IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2263944/releaseinfo)?

Comment: @VedranŠego That's the wrong movie :)

Comment: @coleopterist I know that now, but he asked for an unreleased "Dragon Ball Z" movie. Anyway, my point (to just check IMDb) remains. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2009 movie was not Dragon Ball Z, but [Dragonball: Evolution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1098327/). Going by the reviews, you don't really want to see it.

The movie was released "worldwide" in 2009. In India (as per the OP's profile), it was [released on 7 Aug, 2009](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1098327/releaseinfo).